# Prepaid SIM card with data-only plan in Slovenia?

Tags: budget, cellphones, internet, data-plans, slovenia

I'm going to stay in Slovenia for a week. I'd like to buy a prepaid SIM card with a data-only plan. I only found [this offer](http://www.tusmobil.si/uploads/docs/pogoji/Posebni%20pogoji%20uporabe%20storitev%20mobilnega%20interneta%20-%20MOBILNI%20INTERNET%2024%20UR.pdf) [PDF]. It's from Tusmobil and charges 1€ for 24h of usage.

It's ideal because I would pay only when I use it, but I wasn't able to understand (I used Google Translator) if I have to buy it together with another plan (Free2GO?). I would not want to pay unneeded costs; anyone here knowing Slovenian language can chime in? Other suggestions are much appreciated.

**EDIT:** I was able to understand that the SIM card has a base cost of 5€. It's still very affordable though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDF you provided is both in Slovenian and English language. The English part starts roughly in the middle, so there is no need to translate.

Be aware that Tušmobil's cell coverage is not very good outside major cities and other populated areas. To cover the grey area, they have an agreement with the national cell provider Telekom Slovenije, formerly known as Mobitel. *But* that does not apply for the 24-hour internet for 1€. For that, you *must* be using Tušmobil's cell network.

Your other options are

- **Telekom Slovenije**. This is the best and most popular network, and also the most expensive. Here you have an option for 9,90€ and you get 1 day of internet access, additional days are 2€. You can also get a 30-day option for 10€, which is a better option if you intend to use it for more than 5 days. See [this](http://www.telekom.si/zasebni-uporabniki/mobiteli-in-naprave/ostalo/predplacniski-mobilni-internet-sim-kartica-vkljucuje-1-dan-uporabe-interneta) and [this](http://www.telekom.si/zasebni-uporabniki/paketi/vsi-paketi/paketi-predplacniski-mobilni-internet).
- **Simobil**. This is the second most popular network, it is good in populated areas but the reception in other areas is poorer than Telekom Slovenije. But it is still better than Tušmobil. Here you have an option for 5€ and get a 3-day internet access with that. Additional 3-days will cost you 5€, 30-days will cost you 10€. See [this](https://www.simobil.si/simpl-predplacniska-ponudba/paket-simplnet) and [this](https://www.simobil.si/mobilni-internet/racunalnik-tablica/obstojeca-naprava/predplacniski).

Overall, a week's worth of mobile internet won't cost you more than 10-20€. If you are intending to stay in larger cities, go for the cheapest option. But if you are planning on going to the mountains, national parks and other distant areas, then be aware that Telekom Slovenije (Mobitel) has better coverage than Tušmobil and Simobil.

Comment: Thanks! I had not understood that with the 24-hour option one was stuck with Tusmobil's own network. I think Simobil is the cheapest option for my case. Thanks again for the useful information!

Comment: I may forgot to mention that Simobil's prepaid option has a regular price of 10€ and is currently discounted to 5€, but this lasts only until end of August 2015. After that you will probably have to pay the full price.